# How to change Ubuntu 14.04 logo and BIOS logo?

Tags: 14.04, bios, logo

I've tried making some searches but i can-t manage to find anything about this or it's not understandable, so i keep installing useless stuff and getting more confused about how i change the Ubuntu logo and the BIOS Logo on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change what your BIOS does.  For the few seconds between grub and the time X11 takes over, `plymouth` displays a splash screen.  You can customize it by taking the files in `/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/` and copying them to another directory, modifying ubuntu-logo.plymouth to specify another `ImageDir` and putting your own .png image there, then use `update-alternatives` to redirect `plymouth.default` from `/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth` to your version.

Comment: it was really usefull, and im understanding it better, but im not understanding after i copy the file :c